# is it possible to turned off IOMMU for the megasr driver?

Tags: kernel

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

is it possible to turned off IOMMU for the megasr driver alone,  looks like megasr driver which doesn't fully support the IOMMU

````
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro default_hugepagesz=1GB hugepagesz=1G hugepages=32 intel_iommu=on iommu=pt net.ifnames=0 ipv6.disable=1 biosdevname=0 quiet default_hugepagesz=1GB hugepages=87 hugepagesz=1G intel_iommu=on iommu=pt log_buf_len=4M quiet```


```Sep 18 08:15:24 localhost kernel: [22695.144607] mpt3sas_cm0: search for raid volumes: start
Sep 18 08:15:24 localhost kernel: [22695.145456] scsi target0:1:0: handle(0x0143), wwid(0x008621a5f59b2e1b)
Sep 18 08:15:24 localhost kernel: [22695.146376] mpt3sas_cm0: search for responding raid volumes: complete
Sep 18 08:15:24 localhost kernel: [22695.147173] mpt3sas_cm0: search for expanders: start
Sep 18 08:15:24 localhost kernel: [22695.147973] mpt3sas_cm0: search for expanders: complete
Sep 18 08:15:24 localhost kernel: [22695.148750] mpt3sas_cm0: mpt3sas_base_hard_reset_handler: SUCCESS
Sep 18 08:15:24 localhost kernel: [22695.149535] mpt3sas_cm0: _base_fault_reset_work: hard reset: success
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.180905] mpt3sas_cm0: removing unresponding devices: start
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.181737] mpt3sas_cm0: removing unresponding devices: end-devices
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.182527] mpt3sas_cm0: Removing unresponding devices: pcie end-devices
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.183289] mpt3sas_cm0: removing unresponding devices: volumes
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.184023] mpt3sas_cm0: removing unresponding devices: expanders
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.184740] mpt3sas_cm0: removing unresponding devices: complete
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.185464] mpt3sas_cm0: scan devices: start
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.186260] mpt3sas_cm0:   scan devices: expanders start
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.186985] mpt3sas_cm0:   break from expander scan: ioc_status(0x0022), loginfo(0x310f0400)
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.187687] mpt3sas_cm0:   scan devices: expanders complete
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.188408] mpt3sas_cm0:   scan devices: phys disk start
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.189230] mpt3sas_cm0:   break from phys disk scan: ioc_status(0x0022), loginfo(0x00000000)
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.189991] mpt3sas_cm0:   scan devices: phys disk complete
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.190760] mpt3sas_cm0:   scan devices: volumes start
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.191626] mpt3sas_cm0:   break from volume scan: ioc_status(0x0022), loginfo(0x00000000)
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.192462] mpt3sas_cm0:   scan devices: volumes complete
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.193321] mpt3sas_cm0:   scan devices: end devices start
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.194540] mpt3sas_cm0:   break from end device scan: ioc_status(0x0022), loginfo(0x310f0400)
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.195433] mpt3sas_cm0:   scan devices: end devices complete
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.196340] mpt3sas_cm0:   scan devices: pcie end devices start
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.197276] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x3003011d): originator(IOP), code(0x03), sub_code(0x011d)
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.198229] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x3003011d): originator(IOP), code(0x03), sub_code(0x011d)
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.199179] mpt3sas_cm0:   break from pcie end device scan: ioc_status(0x0021), loginfo(0x3003011d)
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.200143] mpt3sas_cm0:   pcie devices: pcie end devices complete
Sep 18 08:15:25 localhost kernel: [22696.201151] mpt3sas_cm0: scan devices: complete
````

````
Sep 18 07:22:52 localhost kernel: [19543.860887] DMAR: [DMA Read] Request device [81:00.0] PASID ffffffff fault addr 0 [fault reason 06] PTE Read access is not set
Sep 18 07:22:53 localhost kernel: [19544.548561] mpt3sas_cm0 fault info from func: _base_make_ioc_ready
Sep 18 07:22:53 localhost kernel: [19544.549842] mpt3sas_cm0: fault_state(0x2667)!
Sep 18 07:22:53 localhost kernel: [19544.551047] mpt3sas_cm0: sending diag reset !!
Sep 18 07:22:54 localhost kernel: [19545.663077] mpt3sas_cm0: diag reset: SUCCESS
Sep 18 07:22:54 localhost kernel: [19545.664409] mpt3sas_cm0: _transport_smp_handler: timeout```
````

Comment: If you need to disable a driver it is possible to simply [blacklist](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-blacklist-a-module-on-ubuntu-debian-linux) it and prevent it from loading.